# Can't find System.IO.Fakes.ShimDirectory.GetAccessControl

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes, shim

I am using `ShimsContext` in my unit test

I do not found how to fake the `Directory.GetAccessControl` property

I have the `ShimDirectory`, but this property is not exist

Thanks